# javascript console.log and alert not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, alert, console.log

I am trying to debug a javascript file, but I can't seem to print anything to the log or even use the alert function within the file. I know that the file is being run because the .hide() and .show() functions are being properly triggered. I'm using Chrome as my browser. The code is as follows:

```
document.addEventListener("intakeqAppointmentBooked", function(event) {
    alert("test");
    $("#intakeq").hide();
    $("#intakeq-window").hide();
    console.log(event.detail);
    var appointment = event.detail;
    var apptDateFormatted = appointment.dateFormatted;
    var apptDate = appointment.Date;
    var clientName = appointment.ClientName;
    var clientEmail = appointment.ClientEmail;
    var confirmation = "An appointment for " + clientName + " has been booked for " + apptDateFormatted + ". Check " + clientEmail + " for a confirmation email.";
    $("#confirmation").html(confirmation);
    $("#intakeq-confirmation-window").show();
    alert(clientEmail);
```

The divs are properly hiding and showing, and the html is being updated properly with the supplied variables. However, no alert pops up and nothing is logged to the console. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds like maybe JS is cached with it "working" and your alerts aren't being added in.  Can you change this line `$("#confirmation").html(confirmation);` to `$("#confirmation").html("test confirmation");` and see if that takes effect?

Comment: Also, really the best case solution is to use break points in the Chrome developer tools: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/breakpoints

Comment: Did you override either of the functions? Maybe checked the "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs" box? Are all logging options enabled under the Chrome developer tools console tab?

Comment: Andrew Jackman was right, I just needed to clear my cache. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just needed to clear my cache to implement new version of JS file.